# How to put javascript inside media query condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I would like to put javascript inside the media query condition. I want to change the behavior of the elements when the screen is resized into mobile view. This is my code.

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.address0.fa-angle-double-down').on('click', function(event) {        
    jQuery("#address-1").toggleClass("expand");
    jQuery('.address0.fa-angle-double-down').toggleClass("less-text");
    });
    });
    </script>
    }
```

this is the html

```
    <div class="place">
    <h3><a href="/#/"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Nevada</a><i 
    class="fa fa-angle-double-down address0" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>
    <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <a href="/#/">Las Vegas</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Please help thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't add script inside CSS

Comment: CSS and JavaScript are two very different, separate things. You can't put HTML or JavaScript into CSS rules. To do what you want, add an `onload` / `onresize` listener to `window` and set things up in there.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9fwm3zpy/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm new in javascript so i'm still adjusting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check jQuery's `width()` function. You might need to listen to the resize event in conjunction with [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce) function from lodash js library to handle cases in which the window resizes.

```js
    
    function handleClick(e) {
          $("#address-1").toggleClass("expand");
          $('.address0.fa-angle-double-down').toggleClass("less-text");
    }
    
    function handleState() {
    console.log($(document).width());
      if($(document).width() < 767) {
        $('.address0.fa-angle-double-down').on('click', handleClick);
      }
     }
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      handleState();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="place">
    <h3><a href="/#/"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Nevada</a><i 
    class="fa fa-angle-double-down address0" aria-hidden="true"> down</i></h3>
    <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <a href="/#/">Las Vegas</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. gonna try it later. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

do it in Jquery  `if ($(window).width() < 767)`:

```js
$('.address0.fa-angle-double-down').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(window).width() < 767) {
    $("#address-1").toggleClass("expand");
    $('.address0.fa-angle-double-down').toggleClass("less-text");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="place">
  <h3><a href="/#/"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Nevada</a><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down address0" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <a href="/#/">Las Vegas</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Thank you sir. gonna try it later. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but not in CSS. You have to create a [MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries) object to do so.

In your case you will have probably something like:

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 767px)")

// this is called when the MQL status changed
mql.addListener(doStuff);

// this is called if the MQL already matches the query specificed
if (mql.matches) {
   doStuff();
}
```

Check the link for futher details, and be aware of the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia) (nowadays you shouldn't have much problem, but if you have to support IE9 is a different mattern, for example).

Hope it helps.

Comment: It helped a lot sir. Thanks for the response :)